# CSS file being read as HTML file

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to link a css stylesheet to my django html template but it keeps being read as an html file with the error:

> 127.0.0.1/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static_cdn/css/base-template.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

This is my base.html file and I know the path is correct because VS Code directs me to the file when I left-click on the link.

```
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../static_cdn/css/base-template.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">    
        <title>GuitarShop</title>
    </head>
```

Here is my directory:

Project Folder

- guitarshop > templates > base.html
- static_cdn > css > base-template.css

The reason why I am storing the css file in the static_cdn folder instead of a static folder in the templates folder is because when I do so, the command "python manage.py collectstatic" doesn't collect the file folder so I get the following error:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/base-template.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Please help!

Comment: Have you pointed your "Static_URL" to static_cdn folder? How about putting in "STATICFILES_DIRS"?

Comment: Thanks dude, I just forgot to add the static templates folder to "STATIC_URL"

Comment: I might as well put it as the answer so this question will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you pointed your "Static_URL" to static_cdn folder?